# how to include php in wordpress footer and call on pages

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

I am currently putting in php code in my wordpress footer. For example,

```
$a = "Hi";
```

and on my wordpress page i try to `echo $a;` but only get blank and not "Hi. Is there a way to solve this? P.s I am usuing WordPress's admin dashboard

Any help would be appreciated

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Variables are not passed between template files (header, footer, etc.). You can make it global.

```
global $a;
```

And then echo it. 
Also note the order : if get_footer(); si called after, then you can't echo it before...

Comment: Hi barakadam, thanks for the quick reply. just added it on the footer but still no luck on the page itself. I assume it was global $a; $a = "Hi"; then on the page i want to display, echo $a; ?